# Visual Studio SetupProject - How to set Setup version from AssemblyFileVersion of executable

Tags: c#, .net

In a SetupProject (Visual Studio), How to set 'Version' from AssemblyFileVersion of the main executable?

The goal is to keep installer version and main assembly version always synchronized

Comment: Be aware the vs setup projects are no longer available in recent versions. If you want to have something that keeps on working, consider switching to WiX.

Comment: @spender it's not completely true, an extension for vs 2013 just has been released [http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)

Comment: Cool! I thought they'd killed vdproj for good.